# finding number of array from user input

Tags: scripts

```
echo -n "Which station or stations you want to download?"
read station
ELEMENTS=${#station[@]}
for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
    echo you chose ${station[${i}]} stations to download data
done
```

station must be 4 characters, if user write more than one station I need to check the array's number of station inputs. For example if user writes brmu ankr ista. How can I define the number of inputs of station variable and control its character number?

Comment: so user can input multiple 4 char stations separated by space..is there a maximum limit on the number of stations one can enter?

Comment: there is no limit for the number of stations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for`-loop that goes through each item and checks the character count with `wc -m` command.

Here's your script, edited. I apologize if I use somewhat different syntax for looping , but that's just what I'm used to.

```
serg@ubuntu[/home/xieerqi] 
$ cat stations.sh                                                                                                                      
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Which station or stations you want to download?"
read station

for item in $station; do
   NUM=$(printf $item | wc -m)
     if [ $NUM -gt 4 ]; then
    echo "Error: number of chars in $item greater than 4"
    exit 1
     fi
done

ELEMENTS=${#station[@]}
for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
    echo you chose ${station[${i}]} stations to download data
done 


serg@ubuntu[/home/xieerqi] 
$ ./stations.sh
```

E.g. If your station's names are `asdf`, `yolo` and `swag`, you chose the `asdf yolo swag` parameter to download data:

```
serg@ubuntu[/home/xieerqi] 
$ ./stations.sh                                                                                                                        
Which station or stations you want to download? asdf qwerty swag
Error: number of chars in qwerty greater than 4
```

**Notice** that I use printf, not echo. echo outputs additional trailing line, so that messes up the character count. If you'd prefer using echo, then use `echo -n` to avoid printing that newline